# Python3 Get URL creation_date, updated_date and expired_date

Tags: python

I have a URL DataFrame. My coding aims to use machine learning to classify the url into benign or malicious.
I wanna use Host-Based features to get the the url creation_date, last_updated_date and expired_date with whois package. But it shows error.
Could somebody help me to fix it?

Here is my code and the error as following.

```
# URL DataFrame
URL Lable
0   http://ovaismirza-politicalthoughts.blogspot.com/   0
1   http://www.bluemoontea.com/ 0
2   http://www.viettiles.com/public/default/ckedit...   1
3   http://173.212.217.250/hescientiststravelled/o...   1
4   http://www.hole-in-the-wall.com/    0


### Code    
date = []
for i in range(len(df)):
item = df["URL"].loc[i]
domain = urlparse(item).netloc
cr = whois.query(domain).creation_date
up = whois.query(domain).last_updated
exp = whois.query(domain).expiration_date
if cr is not None and up is not None and exp is not None:
    date.append(0)
else:
    date.append(1)

### ErrorException                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-0d7930e66020> in <module>
  3     item = df["URL"].loc[i]
  4     domain = urlparse(item).netloc
----> 5     cr = whois.query(domain).creation_date
  6     up = whois.query(domain).last_updated
  7     exp = whois.query(domain).expiration_date

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whois/__init__.py in query(domain, force, cache_file, slow_down, ignore_returncode)
 48 
 49         while 1:
---> 50                 pd = do_parse(do_query(d, force, cache_file, slow_down, ignore_returncode), tld)
 51                 if (not pd or not pd['domain_name'][0]) and len(d) > 2: d = d[1:]
 52                 else: break

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whois/_1_query.py in do_query(dl, force, cache_file, slow_down, ignore_returncode)
 42         CACHE[k] = (
 43                         int(time.time()),
---> 44                         _do_whois_query(dl, ignore_returncode),
 45         )
 46                 if cache_file: cache_save(cache_file)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whois/_1_query.py in _do_whois_query(dl, ignore_returncode)
 59         r = p.communicate()[0]
 60         r = r.decode() if PYTHON_VERSION == 3 else r
---> 61         if not ignore_returncode and p.returncode != 0: raise Exception(r)
 62         return r
 63 

Exception: whois: connect(): Operation timed out
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

refer:        whois.verisign-grs.com

domain:       COM

organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston Virginia 20190
address:      United States

contact:      administrative
name:         Registry Customer Service
organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston Virginia 20190
address:      United States
phone:        +1 703 925-6999
fax-no:       +1 703 948 3978
e-mail:       info@verisign-grs.com

contact:      technical
name:         Registry Customer Service
organisation: VeriSign Global Registry Services
address:      12061 Bluemont Way
address:      Reston Virginia 20190
address:      United States
phone:        +1 703 925-6999
fax-no:       +1 703 948 3978
e-mail:       info@verisign-grs.com

nserver:      A.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.5.6.30 2001:503:a83e:0:0:0:2:30
nserver:      B.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.33.14.30 2001:503:231d:0:0:0:2:30
nserver:      C.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.26.92.30 2001:503:83eb:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      D.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.31.80.30 2001:500:856e:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      E.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.12.94.30 2001:502:1ca1:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      F.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.35.51.30 2001:503:d414:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      G.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.42.93.30 2001:503:eea3:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      H.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.54.112.30 2001:502:8cc:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      I.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.43.172.30 2001:503:39c1:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      J.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.48.79.30 2001:502:7094:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      K.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.52.178.30 2001:503:d2d:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      L.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.41.162.30 2001:500:d937:0:0:0:0:30
nserver:      M.GTLD-SERVERS.NET 192.55.83.30 2001:501:b1f9:0:0:0:0:30
ds-rdata:     30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CFC41A5766

whois:        whois.verisign-grs.com

status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://www.verisigninc.com

created:      1985-01-01
changed:      2017-10-05
source:       IANA

   Domain Name: VIETTILES.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 1827514943_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.pavietnam.vn
   Registrar URL: http://www.pavietnam.vn
   Updated Date: 2018-09-07T01:13:32Z
   Creation Date: 2013-09-14T04:35:12Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2019-09-14T04:35:12Z
   Registrar: P.A. Viet Nam Company Limited
   Registrar IANA ID: 1649
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@pavietnam.vn
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +84.19009477
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited       https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: NS1.PAVIETNAM.VN
   Name Server: NS2.PAVIETNAM.VN
   Name Server: NSBAK.PAVIETNAM.NET
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
```

> > > Last update of whois database: 2018-12-25T13:33:54Z <<<

By the way, can I use other methods to get the URL creation_date, updated_date and expired_date instead of Whois in Python3?

Thanks in advance!